# Is it possible to use MongoDb with Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, database

I've seen some drivers on Github, they go back to 2012, is there more updated support for Mongodb? Is there a guide I can follow to install run Joomla on Mongodb? I'm considering using the latest Joomla version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb is not a supported database. It is recommended to work on the officially supported databases: http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

```
Supported Databases:
MySQL (InnoDB support required)
SQL Server
PostgreSQL
```

Comment: okay thank you sir